# My css transition works only one way

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I am trying to make a collapse/expand feature to a text field with css transition, but it only works when collapsing.

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle-text collapsed">
Click sdlkfmglksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdkfbmsldkfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmskldfmblksdmflkbmsdflkbmsdlkfbmksldfmbklsdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmfblksdmflbkmsdflkbmslkdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsldkfmbklsdmfbklmsdlfkbmlksdfmblksmdflbkmsdlkfbmlksdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksmdflkbmsdlkffblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmfblksdmflbkmsdflkbmslkdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsldkfmbklsdmfbklmsdlfkbmlksdfmblksmdflbkmsdlkfbmlksdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksmdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmffblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmfblksdmflbkmsdflkbmslkdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsldkfmbklsdmfbklmsdlfkbmlksdfmblksmdflbkmsdlkfbmlksdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksmdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmffblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmfblksdmflbkmsdflkbmslkdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsldkfmbklsdmfbklmsdlfkbmlksdfmblksmdflbkmsdlkfbmlksdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksmdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmffblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmfblksdmflbkmsdflkbmslkdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsldkfmbklsdmfbklmsdlfkbmlksdfmblksmdflbkmsdlkfbmlksdfmblksdmfblkmsdflkbmsdlkfmbklsdfmblksmdflkbmsdlkfmblksdmfmblksdmfbMe
></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toggle-text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 250px;
  transition: height 500ms;
  margin: 0 200px 0 200px;
}
.collapsed {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.expanded{
    height: 400px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.collapsed, .expanded').on('click', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('collapsed expanded');
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/fj639rc6/166/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is without `overflow: hidden` the `<span>` has indefinite size, so it doesn't know what size it's animating towards. Thus it animates towards `infinity`, which obviously happens instantaneously. One options is to try `overflow: scroll`:

https://jsfiddle.net/fj639rc6/168/

Regardless, I think you're going to need to know the resulting height of the span if you want to animate.